# How to toggle contents when related checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I can't get my logic straight! I have 4 checkboxes in divs (called 'bandPackageCheck'), each one that will show different content when clicked (in divs called 'greenBox').

When I click one checkbox, I want it to 'slideToggle' in its respective 'greenBox' div, but have the other ones do nothing (unless they're clicked later on). Then, if the user DOES click another one, I want to keep the previously-clicked ones open as well (unless the user clicks to close them).

I gave the 4 checkboxes IDs, but didn't want to use a different code for each one. How can I do this efficiently?

HTML:

```
<div class="bandPackageCheck">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
    <label for="trioCheckBox"><span>Checkbox 1</span></label>
</div>    

<div class="greenBox" id="content1">

<div class="bandPackageCheck">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
    <label for="checkbox2"><span>Checkbox 2</span></label>
</div>    

<div class="greenBox" id="content2">

<div class="bandPackageCheck">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
    <label for="checkbox3"><span>Checkbox 3</span></label>
</div>    

<div class="greenBox" id="content3">

<div class="bandPackageCheck">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4">
    <label for="checkbox4"><span>Checkbox 4</span></label>
</div>    

<div class="greenBox" id="content4">
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    display:none; 
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:before{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "\f196"; 
    letter-spacing: 10px; 
    color: deepskyblue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f146"; 
  letter-spacing: 10px; 
  color: deepskyblue;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
var checkbox = $(".bandPackageCheck");
var greenBox = $(".greenBox");

$(checkbox).on('change', function(){
    if (this.checked){
        $(greenBox).slideToggle(200);
        $(greenBox).not(this).hide();
    } else {
       $(greenBox).slideToggle(200);
      }
});
```

Thanks for any advice you can offer! I'm kind of new to jQuery as well, so I may not know the most advanced methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `toggle`, be more explicit with `slideDown` and `slideUp`. Then, be more specific about which element you want to manipulate. Also, why are you hiding anything when a box is checked? Finally, don't use `on` unless you need event delegation. It just makes your code more complex.

```
// don't bother creating a variable for this unless you need it elsewhere
$('.bandPackageCheck input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

     // up to the first ancestor .bandPackageCheck encountered, 
    //  then across to the next sibling .greenBox
    var box = $(this).closest('.bandPackageCheck').next('.greenBox');

    if (this.checked) {
        // checked => down; don't leave room for ambiguity with toggle
        $(box).slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $(box).slideUp(200);
    }
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p1z7ygu0/)**

Note that I corrected your faulty HTML by closing all `.greenBox` elements.

Answer (score 0):

The element you are querying for you check box is wrong. You are querying the div that contains the checkbox, not the checkbox itself. It should be

`var checkbox = $('.bandPackageCheck input[type="checkbox"]');`

With that being said here is an alternative solution using vanilla javascript. It utilizes CSS transitions for the slide animation.

http://codepen.io/realseanp/pen/mPaWMj

JS

```
const checkboxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'));
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let {checked} = e.currentTarget;
    let {id} = e.currentTarget.dataset;
    let contentWrap = document.querySelector(`.content[data-id="${id}"]`);
    let inner =  document.querySelector(`[data-id="${id}"] .inner`);
    if(checked) {
      contentWrap.style.height = window.getComputedStyle(inner).getPropertyValue('height');
    } else{
      contentWrap.style.height = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

CSS

```
label {
  display: block;
}
.content {
  height: 0;
  transition: .25s height ;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<label>
  <input data-id="1" type="checkbox">
  Check ME!
</label>

<div data-id="1" class="content">
  <div class="inner">
  Here is some great content for checkbox 1.
  </div>
</div>

<label>
  <input data-id="2" type="checkbox">
  Check ME #2!
</label>

<div data-id="2" class="content">
  <div class="inner">
      Here is some great content for checkbox 2.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While technically impressive, this is rather difficult to read, and it depends on incremented attribute values in the markup.